# Recommended use of non-file-visiting revert-buffer-function

Tags: major-mode, revert-buffer

#### Summary

I am working on a major mode derived from `special-mode`, which populates its buffers with formatted lists of items retrieved from a web API. Reverting such a buffer involves refetching and reformatting said list of items. I would appreciate advice on whether to tailor this custom function to `revert-buffer-function` or to make it standalone.

#### Initial thoughts

For `revert-buffer-function`:

- Better integration/consistency with rest of Emacs

  - `revert-buffer` is already bound to `g` in parent `special-mode-map`
  - running `{before,after}-revert-hook` in `revert-buffer-function` makes sense and affords more customisability

For standalone revert command:

- Allow custom `interactive` arguments

  - For example, how many items to fetch
  - `revert-buffer-function` arguments make little to no sense in a non-file-visiting context and cannot be reused for an alternative purpose

    - Prefix argument to `revert-buffer` cannot easily be retrieved from `revert-buffer-function` - this probably begs a new SE question
- Docstring becomes clearer, more specific and more readily accessible, i.e. the user does not have to read about `revert-buffer`, inspect `revert-buffer-function` or ignore the file-visiting-specific arguments

#### Practical examples

- `eww.el` provides a standalone `eww-reload` command with custom `interactive` arguments, but also comments `FIXME: revert-buffer-function instead!`
- Most non-file-visiting modes I have come across both within and without the Emacs tree are more or less evenly split between rolling out a custom command and using `revert-buffer-function` with ignored argument(s)

#### Conclusion

The fact that the prefix argument to `revert-buffer-function` is file-visiting-specific, together with `last-prefix-arg` not being usefully bound to the prefix argument to `revert-buffer`, suggest `revert-buffer-function` is not really intended for non-file-visiting purposes and so it is unnecessary to seek too deep a level of integration with this mechanism. Is this a sound conlusion? Is there a better use of `revert-buffer-function` or similar mechanisms than the way described herein? Would extending the flexibility of `revert-buffer` constitute a useful feature request?

Comment: 1. You seem to have laid out the advantages and disadvantages. What else are you looking for, as an answer? 2. `revert-buffer-function`*is* intended also for non-file-visiting purposes. There are plenty of modes that use it as such.

Comment: @Drew 1. I am looking for a second opinion from a more experienced package maintainer like yourself on which approach holds most merit and whether there are any workarounds to the drawbacks I have mentioned, though I gather that, as usual, it boils down to "do as you see fit." 2. Indeed, I mention coming across many such cases, but it seems to have been designed primarily with file-visiting in mind.

Comment: @Drew 1. (continued) Anyone inclined to answer may also be able to confirm or correct any of my interpretations.

Comment: When you use `revert-buffer-function`, you have a chance to enable also `auto-revert-mode` for your buffers.